# Javascript function only works if there's an alert for normal redirection

Tags: javascript

Below is code which is use to redirect the URL and not working on Mozilla Browser

```
#Working Code#
alert("HI");
var logouturl = getCookie("ch_logout_url");
location.replace(logouturl);

#Not Working Code#
var logouturl = getCookie("ch_logout_url");
location.replace(logouturl);
```

Comment: Is the issue isolated to Firefox? I'm guessing the alert is stalling the execution just long enough for some resources to load. Could you show `getCookie`?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code in:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // ...
}); //Vanilla Js Alternative to jquery(document).ready();
```

or

```
(function() {
  // ... your code
})(); //Immediately Invoked Function Expression
```

Then your code will run only when the page is already loaded, not absolutely true for the second example but will still work.